# Javascript merge object children to a new object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to merge obj's children to be a new object.

```
const obj = {
  "1": {"string1": "string11"},
  "2": {"string2": "string22"},
  "3": {"string33": "string33"},
  "4": {"string44": "string144"},
};
```

`Object.assign` is able to merge multiple objects 
can do this way:

`Object.assign({}, obj[1], obj[2], obj[3], obj[4])`

However, if obj is a dynamic object, more children objects would be added like

```
const obj = {
  "1": {"string1": "string11"},
  "2": {"string2": "string22"},
  "3": {"string3": "string33"},
  "4": {"string4": "string44"},
  "523": {"string5": "string55"}
  "more": {'something', "new string"}
  . . .
};
```

How to merge them automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(obj))
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the answer

Comment: Will take the answer. Thanks. If use loop like `for (let key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
  }
}` how to merge `(obj[key])` use this way? just curious if it is easy as well. thanks

Comment: You can just merge one by one. Put `let result = {}` before the loop and `Object.assign(result, obj[key])` inside.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot